# How to extract list of element based on list index (Not pandas default index)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I extract the first, second, and 3rd elements from all rows? There are 4217 rows.

Here is my code:

```
0       [38, 24, 35]
1       [38, 24, 35]
2       [34, 24, 35]
3       [34, 26, 38]
4       [34, 26, 38]
        ...     
4212    [34, 27, 35]
4213    [35, 32, 38]
4214    [34, 27, 35]
4215    [32, 24, 34]
4216    [37, 29, 39]
Name: element_size, Length: 4217, dtype: object
```

I tried this df.element_size[0] but only got this [38, 24, 35]

Comment: taking first, second, third would be taking all columns? so do you want to create a DataFrame with it?

Comment: Yes, I want to create 3 separate columns with these 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
pd.DataFrame(df['elements'].tolist())
```

For asscess the single item in list

```
df['elements'].str[0]
```